# How to pass multiple args to a single variable in bash?

Tags: bash

I have two versions of python installed. Therefore if I need to download packages using pip , I have to use either of :

1. `python3.9 -m pip [args]`
2. `python3.8 -m pip [args]`

What I want is that I want to use `pip39` as a substitute of `pythin3.9 -m` so that if I run `pip39 install something` or `pip39 freeze` then the appropriate commands are executed.

I wrote the following function:

`pip39(){python3.9 -m pip "$1"}`

It works well for `pip39 freeze` since `freeze` is a single argument. But for `pip39 install something` it gives error since 2 arguments were passed and only the first will be taken by bash.

So how to put multiple args in`"$1"` ?

Comment: just put it after first one, or create getops fuction

Comment: Isn't an alias (`alias pip39='python3.9 -m pip'`) all you need?

Comment: @DonHolgo , Can an `alias` take arguments? I dont know , I will try that

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson The alias itself is unaware of the arguments, the shell would just replace `pip39` with `python3.9 -m pip` in the command line. Since the arguments simply follow that, it seems sufficient for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bourne-like shells, `"$1"` expands to the first argument of the function (or of the script if not expanded inside a function) or to the *empty string* if not, `"$2"` would be the second, `"$3"` third... `"${10}"` tenth¹, `"$@"` expands to all supplied arguments.

`${1+"$1"}` expands to the first argument if supplied and nothing (not even an empty string) if not. So `${1+"$1"} ${2+"$2"}` would expand to up to 2 of the first arguments of the function. In the `yash` or `zsh` shells, that can be simplified to `"${@[1,2]}"` (even to `"$@[1,2]"` in `zsh`), and in `ksh93`, `bash` and `zsh` to `"${@:1:2}"`.

`pip39() {python3.9 -m pip "$1"}` is *zsh* syntax however. In `bash` or other Bourne-like shell, you'd need `pip39() { python3.9 -m pip "$1";}` (or simply `pip39() python3.9 -m pip "$1"` in the Bourne shell and most Bourne-like shells, though not bash, posh nor yash).

So here, in bash (as you tagged your question) or zsh (as in the syntax of the code in your question), you'd want:

```
pip39(){ python3.9 -m pip "$@";}
```

To pass all the arguments of `pip39` to `python3.9`, that code being Bourne and POSIX compatible.

Or to pass only a limited number of arguments (here 3 as an example):

```
pip39(){ python3.9 -m pip "${@:1:3}"; } # ksh93, bash, zsh
pip39(){ python3.9 -m pip "${@[1,3]}"; } # zsh, yash
pip39(){ python3.9 -m pip ${1+"$1"} ${2+"$2"} ${3+"$3"}; } # any Bourne-like shell
```

---

<sup>¹ Not in the Bourne shell where you're limited to 9. `$10` would be either  like `${10}` or `${1}0` depending on the shell (POSIX requiring the latter unfortunately) so should be avoided.</sup>